# Illegal polymorphic or qualified type using RankNTypes and TypeFamilies

Tags: haskell, type-families

I've been slowly working on porting the [llvm](https://github.com/alphaHeavy/llvm) package to use data kinds, type families and type-nats and ran into a minor issue when trying to remove the two newtypes used for classifying values (`ConstValue` and `Value`) by introducing a new `Value` type parameterized by its constness.

`CallArgs` only accepts `Value 'Variable a` arguments and provides a function for casting a `Value 'Const a` to a `Value 'Variable a`. I'd like to generalize `CallArgs` to allow each argument to be either `'Const` or `'Variable`. Is this possible to encode this somehow using type families? I think it's probably doable with fundeps.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data Const = Const | Variable

data Value (c :: Const) (a :: *)

type family CallArgs a :: * 
type instance CallArgs (a -> b) = forall (c :: Const) . Value c a -> CallArgs b
type instance CallArgs (IO a)   = IO (Value 'Variable a)
```

... which fails to compile:

```
/tmp/blah.hs:10:1:
    Illegal polymorphic or qualified type:
      forall (c :: Const). Value c a
    In the type instance declaration for `CallArgs'
```

Where the following solution works (equivalent to the legacy code), but requires the user to cast the each constant `Value`:

```
type family CallArgs' a :: * 
type instance CallArgs' (a -> b) = Value 'Variable a -> CallArgs' b
type instance CallArgs' (IO a)   = IO (Value 'Variable a)
```

Comment: Comment for random passers by: the above Illegal polymorphic type error is documented in http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html#type-instance-declarations

Comment: I'm not sure of this, but is the precedence of `forall` such that  `(forall (c :: Const) . Value c a) -> CallArgs b` is different to `forall (c :: Const) . Value c a -> CallArgs`? (i.e. grouping the `forall` more tightly.)

Comment: @dbaupp: `forall` is a variable binding construct, like a lambda, and has essentially the same "precedence"--its scope extends as far to the right as syntactically possible.

Comment: @dbaupp I updated the question. I don't think it fundamentally alters the question though as neither case is supported.

Comment: @NathanHowell Oh, that edit is very surprising! Do you want `CallArgs (a -> b)` to represent a function that can accept either a `Value 'Const a` or a `Value 'Variable a` as its first argument (at the discretion of the person calling the function) or to represent a function that accepts as its first argument a value that can be either a `Value 'Const a` or a `Value 'Variable a` (at the discretion of the function itself)? If the latter, my answer probably needs a bit of an update.

Comment: @DanielWagner it should be the former, a function should accept either const or variable values.

Answer (score 6):

The `CallArgs` you're asking for is kind of like a non-deterministic function which takes `a -> b` and returns either `Value 'Const a -> blah` or `Value 'Variable a -> blah`. One thing you can sometimes to with nondeterministic functions is flip them around; indeed, this one has a deterministic inverse.

```
type family   UnCallArgs a
type instance UnCallArgs (Value c a -> b) = a -> UnCallArgs b
type instance UnCallArgs (IO 'Variable a) = IO a
```

Now, anywhere you would have written a type like

```
foo :: CallArgs t -> LLVM t
```

or something like that, you can write this instead:

```
foo :: t -> LLVM (UnCallArgs t)
```

Of course, you might want to pick a better name than `UnCallArgs`, maybe `Native` or something like that, but doing that well requires a bit of domain knowledge that I don't have.

Comment: I'm still wondering it's something fundamental with type families or just not an implemented feature in GHC? Moving the forall to a position that makes sense still fails to typecheck, from looking at TcMType.lhs:checkValidFamInst this seems to be explicit.

Comment: How is that non-deterministic? It's not returning either of two types, it's returning a single type which contains a quantifier, not really different from a function on values returning another function. That GHC's type-level language is not really higher-order and quantifiers are not first-class entities here is another matter.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Sorry, I didn't intend to imply that there was no deterministic function, only that you could view the function as nondeterministic. I'll adjust a bit.

Comment: @NathanHowell As for whether this is fundamental or merely unimplemented, that I don't really know.

Comment: Foralls aren't allowed on the right hand side of a type instance, and it's a fundamental property of the type system. Couldn't quickly find a reference unfortunately...

Comment: @illissius: I'd be interested if you could find a reference. It being a fundamental property of the type system sounds odd to me--fundamental to how GHC implements the concepts, maybe, or necessary to keep certain other features simple, but not central to the nature of the type system itself.

Comment: No luck unfortunately. So I guess I'll partially retract my statement lacking further evidence. But I remember it coming up for discussion somewhere, somewhen, and someone (presumably Simon) said that it has to be this way, because there are weighty theoretical problems with allowing it. Maybe I'm misremembering. In any case after more than half an hour of googling I can't find it, so I'm giving up for now.

Comment: @illissius: I would certainly believe weighty theoretical problems assuming certain features of Haskell and GHC as givens--there are otherwise sensible type system features that would completely break stuff like type inference or choosing type class instances, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Would wrapping the forall c. in a `newtype AV` work for you?

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data CV = Const | Variable

data Value (c :: CV) (a :: *)

data AV a = AV (forall c. Value c a)

type family CallArgs a :: * 
type instance CallArgs (a -> b) = AV a -> CallArgs b
type instance CallArgs (IO a)   = IO (Value 'Variable a)
```

Comment: That's really no different than it is today. I'd like to have it operate over either type of value.

Comment: `forall (c :: Const) . (Value c a -> CallArgs b)` seems different from `(forall (c :: Const) . Value c a) -> CallArgs b`

Comment: Yes, they are different. But there already exists a conversion function from `Value 'Const a -> Value 'Variable a`, this is how it works today. I don't see that boxing/casting all values or just a subset to be different when using the API, both cases are undesirable.