# Type families can't return a RankN type -- workarounds or alternatives?

Tags: haskell, types, haskell-lens, type-families

I'm playing with an extensible record library, and I'm wanting to write a function `field` that can operate as either a `Lens` or a `Traversal` based on whether or not the `Symbol` key is in the list of keys. The type family is given:

```
type family LensOrTraversal key keys s t a b where
    LensOrTraversal key '[] s t a b = 
        Traversal s t a b
    LensOrTraversal key (key =: val ': xs) s t a b = 
        Lens s t a b
    LensOrTraversal key (foo =: bar ': xs) s t a b = 
        LensOrTraversal key xs s t a b
```

This code gives me an error:

```
/home/matt/Projects/hash-rekt/src/Data/HashRecord/Internal.hs:433:5: 
error:
    • Illegal polymorphic type: Traversal s t a b
    • In the equations for closed type family ‘LensOrTraversal’
      In the type family declaration for ‘LensOrTraversal’
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to reuse the `field` name for both lenses and traversals, as it would allow you to write

```
>>> let testMap = empty & field @"foo" .~ 'a'
>>> :t testMap
HashRecord '["foo" =: Char]
>>> testMap ^. field @"foo" 
'a'
>>> testMap ^. field @"bar"
Type error
>>> testMap ^? field @"bar"
Nothing
```

which follows common `lens` idioms. I can provide an `fieldTraversal` function that does what I want, but I'd prefer to overload the name `field` if possible. How would you work around this limitation of type families?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal polymorphic or qualified type using RankNTypes and TypeFamilies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846284/illegal-polymorphic-or-qualified-type-using-rankntypes-and-typefamilies)

Comment: @AntalSpector-Zabusky perhaps related, but this is definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lens *is* already a traversal, only its Rank2 quantifier doesn't make use of the full constraint (it merely requires `Functor`, not `Applicative`).

```
type Lens s t a b      = ∀ f . Functor f     => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
type Traversal s t a b = ∀ f . Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

It is at the level of this constraint that you should introduce your type family:

```
import GHC.Exts (Constraint)
type family FieldOpticConstraint key keys :: (* -> *) -> Constraint where
  FieldOpticConstraint key '[] = Applicative
  FieldOpticConstraint key (key =: val ': xs) = Functor
  FieldOpticConstraint key (_ ': xs) = FieldOpticConstraint key xs
```

Then `field` should not yield a `LensOrTraversal`, but always a custom Rank2-signature with the *constraint* determined by the type family.

Comment: Nice! If only we had implication constraints, we could express nifty things like "must at least be a `Traversal`". I asked about such ideas some time back. Do you have a tricky way to express the concept without explicit dictionary manipulation?

Comment: Phew, no idea. I suspect it would open a bit of can of worms if we tried obtaining such constraints from arbitrary polymorphic types. Is this even decidable?

Comment: Nice! This solved my problem. Now, I just need to figure out how to case on that information at the value level...